# How to create sql script using SELECT query for phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I need to make following SQL queries a file.sql script to edit the values daily and import it to the mysql database to select the needed postid in the table

```
    SELECT `postid` FROM `posts` WHERE

(`postid` =15735 OR
`postid` =7490830 OR
`postid` =286188 OR
`postid` =396331 OR
`postid` =418844 OR
`postid` =10557 OR
`postid` =10851 OR
`postid` =164320 OR
`postid` =47314 OR
`postid` =20390 )

AND

  `acount`=0

 ;
```

Comment: Have you tried `Google`???

Comment: Yes I tried it for 3 days I am searching